# Django: storing new lines in the database from admin and returning them via REST API

Tags: python, django, rest

I created a web application and I am using the django-generated admin to insert some data. In particular, I have the following field:

```
description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
```

In the admin, it appears as a text area, where I can insert new empty lines. However when I insert something like

> Some text followed by a new emtpy line.
>
> Some other text.

the result I obtain in my HTML page invoking the REST API is something like this:

```
Some text followed by a new emtpy line.   Some other text.
```

So, some spaces appear in place of the new line. If I drop the empty line and just insert a line break, the empty spaces reduce in numbers.

The REST API accessing that field is returning this:

> Some text followed by a new emtpy line.\r\n\r\nSome other text.

How do I preserve the empty lines, given the description is correctly stored into the database?

Answer (score 4):

The problem can be solved by adding a css directive for the text container:

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this with [linebreaks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) It will convert newline to br tag in html.
For example:

```
<p>{{ description | linebreaks}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use autoescape and safe filter, it works not only with /n /r but also with other richtext tags.

I used something like this:

```
   {% autoescape on %}
       <div>{{ description|safe }}</div>
   {% endautoescape %}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the newlines to breaks.

`description = description.replace('\r\n', '<br />')`

In your template, output it with the `safe` filter.

`{{ description | safe }}`

The `safe` filter disables html esacping. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#safe

Comment: That is actually causing the br tag to be written as text.